# scipy/numpy FFT on data from file

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, fft

I looked into many examples of scipy.fft and numpy.fft. Specifically this example [Scipy/Numpy FFT Frequency Analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9456037/scipy-numpy-fft-frequency-analysis) is very similar to what I want to do. Therefore, I used the same subplot positioning and everything looks very similar.

I want to import data from a file, which contains just one column to make my first test as easy as possible.

My code writes like this:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sy
import scipy.fftpack as syfp
import pylab as pyl

# Read in data from file here
array = np.loadtxt("data.csv")
length = len(array)
# Create time data for x axis based on array length
x = sy.linspace(0.00001, length*0.00001, num=length)

# Do FFT analysis of array
FFT = sy.fft(array)
# Getting the related frequencies
freqs = syfp.fftfreq(array.size, d=(x[1]-x[0]))

# Create subplot windows and show plot
pyl.subplot(211)
pyl.plot(x, array)
pyl.subplot(212)
pyl.plot(freqs, sy.log10(FFT), 'x')
pyl.show()
```

The problem is that I will always get my peak at exactly zero, which should not be the case at all. It really should appear at around 200 Hz.

[image]

With smaller range:
[image]

Still biggest peak at zero.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a peak at 200Hz? You have plotted up to frequencies of 600,000, so seeing what happens at 200 Hz is difficult in your plot. You *do* have a DC component in the data though, so I am not so the peak at 0 is probably accurate.

Comment: That said, can we get a plot of the interval [-400,400] or something as well?

Comment: Yes, because even if I just plot from frequencies of -500 to 500 there will just show up one peak at 0. As can be seen here: http://s29.postimg.org/439jgrzon/stack_OFlow_range.png

Comment: Uhm, that is the same data, just with different numbers on the axis.

Comment: Hmm... well what I did is just add this array: `pltfreqs = freqs/100` and then plot by `pyl.plot(pltfreqs, sy.log10(FFT), 'x')` . Is that wrong? Excuse my question, but this is the first time I ever used python.

Comment: No, because that just changes the values on the line, they will still show the same data. You would have to either zoom using e.g. `pyl.xlim(-500,500)` or slice your **data**, and not the **coordinates of the data**.

Comment: Yeah that was really dumb by myself. Just figured that out. Now I still do have the biggest peak at zero and many smaller ones around 200: http://s24.postimg.org/l4izy26t1/stack_OFlow_range_2.png

Comment: Looks reasonable to me.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about signal processing and not programming.

Comment: Yeah you're right. I just thought the peaks should be more significant. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

As already mentioned, it seems like your signal has a DC component, which will cause a peak at f=0. Try removing the mean with, e.g., `arr2 = array - np.mean(array)`.

Furthermore, for analyzing signals, you might want to try plotting power spectral density.:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import matplotlib.mlab as mlb

Fs = 1./(d[1]- d[0])  # sampling frequency
plt.psd(array, Fs=Fs, detrend=mlb.detrend_mean) 
plt.show()
```

Take a look at the documentation of `plt.psd()`, since there a quite a lot of options to fiddle with. For investigating the change of the spectrum over time, `plt.specgram()` comes in handy.